# Rendering a long list of cards

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I'm trying to render a long list of cards with astro but it's performing poorly, I'm not clear if I can use HTML streaming or if I should use a client-side pagination strategy.

This is my list component:

```
---
import Card from "./Card.astro";
const longList = Array.from(Array(200).entries()).map((_, i) => ({ slug: 'card-'+i, name: 'Card '+i}))
---
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  {
    longList.map( card => 
      <Card title={card.name} slug={card.slug} />
    )
  }
</div>
```

- Astro config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [tailwind(), react()],
  output: "server",
  adapter: node({
    mode: "standalone"
  })
});
```

I want Astro to send cards on demand, can I achieve this or should I go for the client-side pagination strategy?

Comment: I just read the Astro document https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/integrations-guide/react/ , Astro isn't suitable for your specific case. However, you can combine Astro with Client-side pagination strategy.

Comment: What does your Card look like? A fairly simple component e.g. one not fetching anything should be fine to render like that.